# Adjust date and time informations inside several text files automatically from the command-line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a folder with several text files which content is something like this:

```
text text
more text
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:53:51 +0000 (UTC)
more text
some more
```

I want that date and time to be correct accordingly to my time zone (in my case, if it says "+0000 (UTC)" I have to add 1 hour, for winter time)

So the result should be the same file (same filename or if you want "adjusteddate_originalfilename") containing:

```
text text
more text
Date: Fri, 1 Jan 2016 00:53:51
more text
some more
```

Note that the line that has to be edited begins with "Date: " (which is unique, there is no other "Date: " in the text file) and ends in "+0000 (UTC)". And it will only be edited if the end of the line is "+0000 (UTC)".

Amongst those files I have others with:

```
text text
text text
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 +0200
text text
text text
```

Those don't need to be adjusted, (in fact I would like that "+0200" to be removed).

These corrections would be made automatically and periodically to all the files contained in "/home/user/folder01" (e.g. I am not in front of this computer). I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Something like (untested): `cat file | sed 's/^Date:.*0000$/Date: $(date)/'` (you'll need to test this, I'm nowhere near a terminal right now, but it's a workable general approach)

Comment: @ssta thanks, but that didn't change anything (I tried with same text as in example)

Comment: So there needs to me more clarification. You want the lines with `+0000 (UTC)` to have time rounded to midnight , right ? or to the nearest hour ? what if the text file says `Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 18:53:51 +0000 (UTC)` ?  What if it says `Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:05:51 +0000 (UTC)` , where does that round up - to midnight or to 23:00:00 ? Do files that contain other UTC time like `+0500` need to be considered or only `+0000` files must be adjusted ?

Comment: @Serg if the text file says Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 18:53:51 +0000 (UTC) the adjusted date should be Thu, 31 Dec 2015 19:53:51 (winter time). For dates before 25th October, it should be adding 2 hours. For now I just have files that are either +0000 (UTC) or +0200. As I said, +0000 dates need to be adjusted, but +0200 are ok, and I only asked how to remove the +0200 part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU `date` to convert that time to your local time zone.

```
 awk '/^Date:.*UTC/ {cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new; close(cmd); $0="Date: " new} 1' file
text text
more text
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 01:53:51 +0200
more text
some more
```

If you have GNU awk, you can change in-place all the files in the current directory using:

```
gawk -i inplace '/^Date:.*UTC/ {cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new; close(cmd); $0="Date: " new} 1' *
```

Without GNU awk, use:

```
for f in *
do
    awk '/^Date:.*UTC/ {cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new; close(cmd); $0="Date: " new} 1' "$f" >tmp && mv tmp "$f"
done
```

#### How it works

- `-i inplace`

  This tells GNU awk to change files in place.  This requires a modern GNU awk.  If you use Mike's awk, then use instead the bash loop as shown above.
- `/^Date:.*UTC/ {cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new; close(cmd); $0="Date: " new}`

  This selects lines that start with `Date:` and contain `UTC` on the same line.  For those lines, the command `date -Rd` is run on the part of the line containing the date.  The result is stored in the variable `new`.  Then, the current line, denoted by `$0` in awk, is replaced by one with the new date.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Multiple line GNU version

If you prefer your scripts spread over multiple lines:

```
gawk -i inplace '

/^Date:.*UTC/ {
    cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new
    close(cmd)
    $0="Date: " new
}

1
' file
```

#### Some refinements (non-GNU version)

1. The code above looks for lines starting with `Date:` that also contain the letters `UTC`.  This appears to me to be good enough.  The question, however, asks more specifically for lines that start `Date:` and end with `+0000 (UTC)`.
2. The question also asks to eliminate the trailing `+0200` from non-UTC date lines.

Adding these two refinements, the code becomes:

```
for f in *
do
    awk '/Date: .* [+]0200$/{sub(/ [+]0200$/,"")} /^Date: .* [+]0000 [(]UTC[)]$/ {cmd="date -Rd \"" substr($0,6) "\""; cmd | getline new; close(cmd); $0="Date: " new} 1' "$f" >tmp && mv tmp "$f"
done
```

This code is more precise but also more persnickety.  For example, this code insists that a line end with `+0000 (UTC)` before it will change it.   Consequently, lines with trailing whitespace, which may be invisible in your editor, will *not* be changed.  Whether this is good or not is something for you to decide.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks, it kind of worked, because what I am getting is Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:53:51 +0100. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: @tom_len That means that your default time zone is UTC+1.   You can change the default using the `TZ` environment variable.  To get the +2 examples in the answer, I used `export TZ=Israel` but you should use whatever location is your actual target.

Comment: @kos Thanks:  I added a bash loop to handle that.

Comment: @John1024 this is what I get if I run timedatectl

    Local time 19:26 CEST
    Universal time 17:26 UTC
    RTC time 17:26
    Time zone Europe/Zurich (CEST, +2000). Everything is correct there, that is my time zone

Comment: Zurich is now +2 but, in the winter, [Zurich in in daylight savings time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/switzerland/zurich).  So, in Dec/Jan, +1 is correct for Zurich.  If you want to be a consistent +2, use `TZ=Etc/GMT-2` (note sign change).  This should eliminate the daylight savings problem.

Comment: @John1024 Yes, you are right, I forgot about daylight saving time, so iin fact I have to edit my initial question and resulting output wanted. Now I really need to try and investigate the removal part of the last part (+0100)

Comment: @kos To my knowledge, the only GNU specific feature was `-i inplace`.  I believe that I have it clearly labeled (and I updated awk-->gawk where it is used).  The bash-loop version should be compatible with generic awk.

Comment: @kos I just test it with Mike's awk and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`perl` for the deletion and `awk` for the `date` part. Replace `foo` with your filename

```
perl -pe 's/^(Date:.*)\+[0-9]{4}$/$1/' foo | \
    awk -F'Date:' '/(UTC)/ {system("echo Date: $(date -d \""$2"\" +\"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S\") "); next} {print $0}'
```

---

*Example*

`cat dates`

```
text text
more text
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:53:51 +0000 (UTC)
more text
some more
text text
text text
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 +0200
text text
text text
text text
more text
Date: Fri, 1 Jan 2016 01:53:51
more text
some more
```

```
perl -pe 's/^(Date:.*)\+[0-9]{4}$/$1/' dates | \
    awk -F'Date:' '/(UTC)/ {system("echo Date: $(date -d \""$2"\" +\"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S\") "); next} {print $0}'
```

```
text text
more text
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 01:53:51
more text
some more
text text
text text
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 
text text
text text
text text
more text
Date: Fri, 1 Jan 2016 01:53:51
more text
some more
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/Date: (.* \+0000 \(UTC\))/$1/?$_="Date: ".`LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date -d "$_" "+%a, %d %b %Y %T"`:s/(Date:.*) \+[0-9]{4}/$1/' in
```

- If the `s/Date: (.* \+0000 \(UTC\))/$1/` substitution, which replaces the whole line with the section after `Date:`, could be made, prints `Date:` followed by the output of `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date -d "$_" "+%a, %d %b %Y %T"`, which converts the substituted part to the current time zone using an `LC_TIME` value of `en_US.UTF-8`; otherwise, if the `s/(Date:.*) \+[0-9]{4}/$1/` substitution,  which replaces the whole line with the section before `+NNNN`, could be made, prints the substituted part; if no substitution could be made, prints the whole line.

This means that the current `LC_TIME` value is set to `en_US.UTF-8` (or equivalent) already, the `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` part is safe to be dropped:

```
perl -pe 's/Date: (.* \+0000 \(UTC\))/$1/?$_="Date: ".`date -d "$_" "+%a, %d %b %Y %T"`:s/(Date:.*) \+[0-9]{4}/$1/' in
```

```
% cat in
line
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:53:51 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 +0200
% perl -pe 's/Date: (.* \+0000 \(UTC\))/$1/?$_="Date: ".`LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date -d "$_" "+%a, %d %b %Y %T"`:s/(Date:.*) \+[0-9]{4}/$1/' in
line
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:53:51
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29
```

To edit the file in-place and to apply this to multiple files, you may add the `-i` switch and pass `*` instead of the filename:

```
% cat in
line
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:53:51 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 +0200
% cat in1
line
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:53:51 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29 +0200
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % perl -i -pe 's/Date: (.* \+0000 \(UTC\))/$1/?$_="Date: ".`LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date -d "$_" "+%a, %d %b %Y %T"`:s/(Date:.*) \+[0-9]{4}/$1/' *
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat in
line
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:53:51
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat in1
line
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:53:51
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 23:07:29
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too taking into account daylight saving time